# best practices with single page websites to decrease page load time without hurting SEO

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm Wondering what are some best practices to decrease page load time of single page websites, and doing so in a way that won't hurt with SEO.

I'm leaning toward an ajax solution with "hijax linking", but I'm wondering what are some best practices in terms of the load order for a page. So for instance, say I have a simple webpage- has home, about, pictures of my cat, contact etc. and I'm planning to have it all show up on the homepage via vertical scrolling-alotting one "screen" worth of content per item.

I'm coding this in wordpress, so my main idea would be to first load the first "screen" i.e. hero section of homepage, as part of the home.php, so the user doesn't have to wait for the whole thing-and SEO. Then once that has finished loading, to load the next four via ajax, in the background. So I'm wondering what the best strategy might be to go about that. Someone provided this answer elsewhere:

"Build a standard 5 page site using php with proper separation of header, footer, content. Then use javascript to redirect to a single (separate) page with all content include()ed on the page."

In wordpress I'd take this to mean. Create a seperate page with a loop the grabs the other four "screens" as posts. and then load this page, after home.php has loaded.. Does anyone see any issues with this approach, or as the question asks, have any better or best practices to accomplish this, I'd appreciate them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things you can do:

1. Need to improve the performance of your back end code in case there
   is any.
2. Pagination: split page in smaller pages
3. Caching
4. Decrease the size of content, decrease the size of background images, compress js content
5. Compress Content

Most of the time the perfect optimization will depend on your situation. To start with one of the above will do it for you.

Comment: Emanuel thanks. What do you think is the best strategy simply for load order? say I have 5 screens worth of content-scrolling vertically- should I try to load it all as part of a single page, or just have the top part be one page, and load the additional screens in after the first one has loaded?

Comment: The best strategy would be to load the first page and load other pages as user scrolls using ajax or use pagination. Even big website like Google avoid long pages they use pagination. Why? to improve performance. Another advice work on your approval rate, that will encourage people to comment/answer your questions.

Comment: got it, I wasn't aware of the approval rate  feature until recently. I was thinking about loading additional "screens" as the user scrolls, but I'd rather avoid the "loading screens" if at all possible. That's why I was thinking of just loading them right after the home.php page has loaded. Or maybe immediately start loading the screen directly bellow the first one, and do so in order, but that would require more http requests presumably, so not sure that would be better. And then ofcourse the user could always click on a menu item, that's way down further on the page, is another issue..

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged with "wordpress". Therefore, I am assuming that  you use wordpress.

if so, what I would think as logical starting point is to use one of the wordpress caching plugins. I use Quick Cache for my [website](http://www.technologyspirit.com) and it makes significant difference.

But, you shouldn't stop with the plugin. Consider the quality of the theme you are using. You must be sure that the theme is good quality. Poorly designed themes may make inefficient database call and may slow your website.

delaying and Loading part of the page with ajax shouldn't be your first optimization action. Try all the other options first.